# Generic implementation of SiftUp/Down operations on binary heap

Tags: c++, generics, template, c++14, heap

Binary heap construction and maintenance boil down to the two basic operations: sift up and sift down. Following are generic template implementations of the two operations. Any comments are welcome. I'm preparing for an interview, and I hope my code will appeal to the interviewer :-)

```
/// Compile with `-std=c++14`.
#include <cassert>
#include <algorithm>
#include <array>
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <utility>

template <class RandIt, class Less = std::less<void>>
void SiftDown(RandIt first, RandIt last, Less&& less = Less{}) {
  auto n = static_cast<unsigned>(last - first);
  if (n < 2) return;
  auto child = 1u;
  if (2 < n && less(first[1], first[2])) ++child;
  if (less(first[0], first[child])) {
    typename std::iterator_traits<RandIt>::value_type val =
      std::move(first[0]);
    first[0] = std::move(first[child]);
    while (true) {
      first += child;
      n = static_cast<unsigned>(last - first);
      if (n < 2) break;
      child = 1u;
      if (2 < n && less(first[1], first[2])) ++child;
      if (! less(val, first[child])) break;
      first[0] = std::move(first[child]);
    }
    first[0] = std::move(val);
  }
}

template <class RandIt, class Less = std::less<void>>
void SiftUp(RandIt first, RandIt last, Less&& less = Less{}) {
  auto n = static_cast<unsigned>(last - first);
  if (n < 2) return;
  auto parent = n / 2 - 1;
  if (less(first[parent], last[-1])) {
    typename std::iterator_traits<RandIt>::value_type val =
      std::move(last[-1]);
    last[-1] = std::move(first[parent]);
    while (true) {
      last = first + parent + 1;
      n = static_cast<unsigned>(last - first);
      if (n < 2) break;
      parent = n / 2 - 1;
      if (! less(first[parent], val)) break;
      last[-1] = std::move(first[parent]);
    }
    last[-1] = std::move(val);
  }
}

int main() {
  int arr[5] = {2, 1, 5, 4, 3};
  auto it = arr;
  while (true) {
    SiftUp(arr, it);
    if (it == arr + 5) break;
    ++it;
  }
  for (auto i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
    std::cout << *arr << ' ';
    std::iter_swap(arr, --it);
    SiftDown(arr, it);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Don't specify the array size in `int arr[5] = {2, 1, 5, 4, 3};`. `int arr[] = {2, 1, 5, 4, 3};` will cause less maintenance issues.
- Don't use magic numbers. All other occurrences of `5` should be replaced with either `sizeof arr / sizeof *arr` or much better turn `arr` into an `std::array` and use `arr.size()`.
- I don't like the combination of `while (true)` with a conditional `break`. Not sure how to get around it though.
- I don't understand what the `static_cast<unsigned>` are for. Casts are not very appealing.
- You use `auto` for basically everything including unsigned ints, but then you explicitly name the type `typename std::iterator_traits<RandIt>::value_type` when `auto` would suffice.
- I would appreciate some comments. I don't actually know what `SiftUp` and `SiftDown` do and why they are not hidden in some heap implementation. I suppose returning when `n < 2` is because you are heapifying the array and an array of less than 2 elements it automatically a heap, but I'm not sure.
- The code in `main` is essentially a demo how to use the code. That is good. You could flesh that out a bit though. I made a move only type to check if you screwed up move semantics somewhere. You probably did too. Leave the check in. Also add an `assert` to make sure the resulting array is `5 4 3 2 1`. (that is the correct result, right?). Therefore, when people <s>mess with</s> optimize the code they will be notified when they screw up. Add a case with an empty array, 1 element array and an array with a bunch of equal elements to show you thought about edge cases.
- `SiftUp` and `SiftDown` could probably use some `assert`s to check if invariants hold. This also documents that there are invariants and what they are and you are told when you break them.
- I would add some line breaks and even parenthesis to if statements. That is a style/habit thing through. If you can get your hands on code written by the interviewer's company try to mimic their style.
- `last` in `SiftDown` should be a `const &` to avoid an unnecessary copy. Same goes or `first` in `SiftDown`, but then you need to pass `std::begin(arr)` instead of just `arr`.

After having criticized a lot let me say this: I would probably hire you. You show a good understanding of C++ and should be easy to shape into a good software developer. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for the detailed and nice review. 1) I explicitly specified the array extent mainly because I don't want the reader to count the size himself. I will use `std::vector` instead. `std::array` cannot have the extent deduced from the initializer. 2) Signed-unsigned conversion can be potentially dangerous. So I made it explicit with `static_cast`. 3) The `value_type` thing is really my fault. Nice catch! 4) You get it right. A single element is a heap trivially.

Comment: 5) I agree with your suggestion about unit testing. But I'm afraid I cannot push it very far, given the limited time for an interview session. 6) I omitted `assert` and some braces, mainly because I want to keep the code compact so I can review it quickly myself for possible issues during an interview. By the way, I get your point and agree with it :-) 7) Since iterators are copied in the standard library. I followed it. Note that, in practice, copy will most probably not happen. Copy elision will kick in. Thanks for the review again and the nice words. It does help :-)